# Is it worth to create new thread per packet handle?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a c# server and it has a packet handler that handles packets of clients like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < packets.Count; i++)
{
   new Thread(new HandlePacket(packets[i].bytes, packets[i].count).handle).Start();
}
```

Usually the handle packet have lots of code to execute (depands on packet id, sometimes even nested loops), the threads are to prevent hanging (or long execution time) the packet handler because one packet handle can sometimes do nested loop like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
   {
      for (int k = 0; k < 32; k++)
      {
      }
   }
}
```

Is it efficient to do such thing?
If not, what are the alternatives to prevent the hanging of packet handler thread?

The server is for a game, long execution (or hang) time is not acceptable.

Additionally every server have 32 packet handlers (one reserved for each client)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend handling threads directly.  Take a look at thread pools and Task-based parallel library (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl)

Comment: It would be best to reserve  a set number of threads and allocate them as needed. I wouldn't generate a new thread for every packet that comes in as that may not be possible. Put your packets in a queue and give them threads as they become available. You can play around with different sizes of thread pools

Answer (score 1):

In order to enable data parallelism on the collection, you could make use of the **Parallel.ForEach()**.
Therefore, your code will look something like this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(packets, (item) =>
{
    new HandlePacket(item.bytes, item.count).handle();
});
```

Comment: Please answer the question "Is it efficient to do such thing?"

Comment: In order to process a collection of data in parallel, it is the most efficient way. Instead of assigning an individual new task (if you use `Task.Run()` or `Task.Factory.StartNew()`) or thread for each item in the collection, you can use `Parallel.ForEach` which has an internal [Partitioner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) class that will create small batches that will run concurrently. The maximum number of batches that you can have is equivalent to the number of items in the collection.

Comment: That still doesn't answer the question.

Comment: How come? You can't process any collection of data, in parallel, with any other method that makes it faster and uses the resources better than a `Parallel.Foreach`. Thus it is the most efficient way to do it.

Comment: The question that was asked is if the OP's approach is efficient or not. You've just answered with what you think is a more efficient way. You're not qualifying or quantifying how much less efficient is the OP's way - or indeed if it is less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `Task` class you allow the runtime to determine how to use Threads to run your code in parallel.

You would do it like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < packets.Count; i++)
{
   Task.Run(() => new HandlePacket(packets[i].bytes, packets[i].count).handle).Start());
}
```

There are some other things you can configure like it, but this will be 
much better than starting a thread for each package.

Comment: Please answer the question "Is it efficient to do such thing?"